# Can't update OpenSusue 12 without Memory Stick

Tags: opensuse

I recently installed OpenSuse using a jump drive that had the openSuse DVD-1 "dd"'ed to it. Everything went fine. However, when I try to install software using zypper or update the system software, I have to have the usb inserted or zypper warns me it's missing a repository and the software updater just spins (don't lock, I can close it). How can I fix this?

Thanks,
JPD

Comment: Thats so stange.
If you were talking about bootloaders, then it could be written in (eg)sdb, instead of sda. But repos don't have that problem, because they are indentified in a file that is somewhere in the root partition. (probably /etc/*.conf).
Do you fix the problem when you instert any pendrive, or just a specific one?

I don't really know how can i help you. Check oSuse irc.

Comment: When I try to run an update, this is the information I get hd:///?device=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Verbatim_STORE_N_GO_07991009E46530FF-0:0-part1. It appears to be looking specifically for the jump drive.

Comment: And you have that pendrive that zypper is claiming?
If so, think what you did before with the pendrive inserted. Did you did any configuration that could be someway related? If you want quicker help, try to ask here: http://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:IRC_list When you find the answer you are looking for, come back and post it as an answer.